# .NET WebApi - How to receive a file with additional parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Noob question here, i'm trying to send a file with one added string parameter.
My uploader class looks like that:

```
 public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc)
        {
            string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            wr.Method = "POST";
            wr.KeepAlive = true;
            wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
            string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
            foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
            {
                rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
                byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
            }
            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
            string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, file, contentType);
            byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            fileStream.Close();
            byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
            rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
            rs.Close();
            WebResponse wresp = null;
            try
            {
                wresp = wr.GetResponse();
                Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
               var result = reader2.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.log.Error(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " Error occurred while converting file ", ex);
                if (wresp != null)
                {
                    wresp.Close();
                    wresp = null;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                wr = null;
            }
        }
```

The string parameters are inside the NameValueCollection.
Now how should the other side, the post method, receive it?

*Also, in this cases where i mix a file + string parameters, should the content type be "application/octet-stream"?

Thanks

Comment: You can return additional parameters in header(s).

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can create a `FileUploadViewModel` to contain all your properties including `IFormFile`. Use this as parameter type to your action method. Default model binder should be able to populate everything for you.

Also see if you need a custom model binder - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Thanks I will try that. About using it as parameter type, where exactly am I doing it?